# How can I solve the following error when. when I try to make a connection to mongo I have the following error "TypeError: db.on is not a function"

Tags: javascript

En el siguiente código:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var mongoDB = 'mongodb://localhost/red_bicicletas';
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {useNewUrlParser: true });
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var db = mongoose.Connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error'));
```

TypeError: db.on is not a function

Comment: can you try the following?  from the docs:                                                                     `mongoose.connection.on('error', err => {
  logError(err);
});`

Comment: I'd just try changing mongoose.Connection -> mongoose.connection. That should solve the error properly,  and your db variable will be usable still.

Comment: Thank you very much, finally this solved my error : 'mongoose.connection.on('error', err => {   logError(err); });' @abestrado